# Problems viewing indexes

Tags: sql, oracle

I've created a very simple index and now I just want to display the information of the index but I can't be able to do it for some reason... I know I have done it before but now I can't manage to. I've tried different methods but I just get errors (Invalid SQL statement). What I'm looking for is a view that is the same as I get when I do `DESC Test_Table` which like this:

[image]

I'm using Oracle Application Express.

The index I've created looks like this:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX Test_Index ON Test_Table(Attribute1, Attribute2)
```

I tried these different methods to display the index but none of them works

```
SELECT Test_Index FROM dba_indexes WHERE table_name='Test_Table';
```

"Table or view does not exist"

```
exec sp_helpindex Test_Table
```

"Invalid SQL statement"

```
SELECT * FROM sysindexes WHERE id = object_id('Test_Table')
```

"Table or view does not exist"

Why am I getting these errors?

Comment: seems like you don;t have privileges to view the dba_indexes. sysindexes don't exist on Oracle. Try querying `user_indexes` table

Comment: @Sathya Running `SELECET Test_Index FROM user_indexes WHERE table_name='Test_Table';` Gives me "Invalid SQL Statement"

Comment: it should be 'select', not 'selecet'. Also, the index name will be part of resultset, not a column name.

Comment: Ah how clumsy of me. Now I get "TEST_INDEX": Invalid identified"

Comment: DESCribe gives info about the *table*, not indexes other than the primary key, and your index isn't a primary key. See @Sathya answer.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you don't have privileges to view the `dba_indexes`. sysindexes don't exist on Oracle, only on SQL Server(from what I gather, anyway - I'm not versed in SQL Server)

The exec thing also is a SQL Server hangover.

Try querying user_indexes table –

```
select index_name from user_indexes
where table_name= 'TEST_TABLE'
```

Note that  SQL is case sensitive whenever something is quoted, so if you pass table name as 'Test_Table' it is likely to fail

Comment: That gives the index name(s). You may also want UNIQUENESS. If you want info on the columns in the index, which would be more *like* DESCribe for a table though not exactly the same, look at `user_ind_columns` (possibly joined 1-n from `user_indexes`).